# What is the use of calling Interface methods in the implemented class?

Tags: c#, .net, interface, asp.net-mvc-5, action-filter

What is the use of calling interface methods within the class that has implemented it instead of implementing the the particular method itself like below -

```
public class MyController: Controller, IActionFilter {
  public ActionResult Index(Customer obj) {
    return View(obj);
  }
  void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) 
  {
    Trace.WriteLine("Action Executed");
  }
  void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) {
    Trace.WriteLine("Action is executing");
  }
}
```

What does calling out methods like this way -> "IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted" achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuted` is an *explicit* implementation of that interface method.

You can only call the `OnActionExecuted` method on a `MyController` instance if you cast your instance to `IActionFilter`.

However if you make an *implicit* implementation like:

```
public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
```

you will be able to call `OnActionExecuted` on a `MyController` instance without casting it as `IActionFilter`

Comment: This helped. Also, looked up Explicit Interface Implementation here (for others like me) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation